# Keybinding when clause visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

The `alt+s` keybinding doesn't work
Reason: when clause is working unexpectedly

How to use when clause to detect if a particular extension is installed and enabled?

when clause reference in docs - [https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts#:%7E:text=Extension%20contexts-,extension,-True%20when%20the)

file `keybindings.json`

```json
{
        "key": "alt+s",
        "command": "java.debug.debugJavaFile",
        "when": "extension == vscjava.vscode-java-debug"
}
```

Comment: the `when` doc is not clear where you can use the `extension***` context keys, the most promising one is `extensionStatus` but for which extension

Comment: @rioV8 the usage is somewhat ambiguous and I could not get any other info on google. `"extensionStatus == installed"` How would this work?

Comment: where did you get that keybinding definition? Did you write it yourself? If so, why did you add that when clause? what are you hoping that it will do? what is your goal?

Comment: @starball the keybinding definition is available from the java debugger extension. I wanted to change the keybinding which works. With the when clause I wanted it to only map  to `alt+s` when the java debugger extension is enabled in vscode

Comment: I do not see such a keybinding provided by the extension by default when scanning the source code for the extension. Are you 100% sure that you didn't add this keybinding yourself?

Comment: Yes I created this keybinding for a command that is provided by the extension which works. I want to enforce a when clause as per vscode support https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts to make the keybinding work only when I have this extension enabled

Comment: Where could I find that?

Comment: I did add comment, but in an edit realized it was incorrect and forgot it was an edit and not the initial text